# Check if Calendar is shared in Apex (can create events for other user as owner)

Tags: apex, sharing, event, calendar

I have a custom LWC and Apex code that work together to allow users to create `Event` objects.

The user can select the `OwnerId` for the newly created events. Due to the unrelated business rules it so mostly happens that this just works and my code does not need to check whether they have access to the Calendar of the target user.

On occasion, however, the user gets the dreaded

> You don't have access to assign events to this calendar. Ask your admin to increase your sharing access level for this calendar. - INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY.Fields affected - OwnerId

Is there any way for me to check beforehand (using Apex/SOQL) whether the User has access to set another User as `OwnerId` on an `Event` object?